# assign different class based to the url

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to dynamically assenare the class "active" to manage the styles of some links.
I have this code but does not work ..

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">  
function locationPathname(){  

    var path = window.location.pathname.split('/');
    path = path[path.length-1];
    alert(path);
    if (path !== undefined) {
    $('livello2 a[href="/' + path + '"]').addClass('active');
  }
    }
 </script>
```

and html:

```
 <div class="livello2">
                 <div class="live">
                     <a href="./Live.php"><img src="live_off.png"></a>
                 </div>
                 <nav class="menu">
                     <ul>
                         <a href="./index.php" ><li>HOME</li></a>
                         <a href="./Concerti.php"><li>CONCERTI</li></a>
                     </ul>
                 </nav>
       </div>
```

css:

```
.active{background-color:red}
```

anyone has any suggestions or sees it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JS you do this:

```
$('.livello2 a[href="/' + path + '"]')
```

(assuming you have added that dot in the beginning of the selector) that would be converted (after calculating the `path` variable) into something like

```
$('.livello2 a[href="/Concerti.php"]')
```

But the actual href attributes in your code start with a `.` (dot) like

```
href="./Concerti.php"
```

So you need to update the JS snippet above to

```
$('.livello2 a[href="./' + path + '"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

replace this one

```
$('livello2 a[href="/' + path + '"]')
```

with this one

```
$('.livello2 a[href="/' + path + '"]')
```

Comment: add .livello2 in front of livello2

Comment: add a dot(.) in front of livello2

Comment: instead of this .active{background-color:red} put this .active{color:red;}

Comment: I try with `$('.livello2.livello2 a[href="/' + path + '"]').addClass('active');` and `$('.livello2 a[href="/' + path + '"]').addClass('active');` but not work. I also changed the css

Comment: instead of this .addClass('active'); try this one .css("color","red");

Comment: Try this one $('.livello2 a[href="/' + path + '"]').css("color","red");

Comment: I try ` $('.livello2 a[href="/' + path + '"]').css("color","red");` but not work...

Comment: and also replace this one a[href="/' + path + '"] with this one a[href="' + path + '"]

Comment: replace this one a[href="/' + path + '"] with this one a[href="' + path + '"]

Comment: `$('.livello2 a[href="' + path + '"]').css("color","red");` either way ...... but it is not that he can not take the children in the class?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20390/discussion-between-stefania-and-murali-prasanth)

Comment: seriously, stop tinkering with the tiny bits of stuff that doesn't make any difference. Switching CSS property from background-color to color makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer from @Murali Prasanth about adding dot in your JS snippet, I would suggest to make sure your javascript block is put right after the closing `</body>`. If it is in the  it's not going to work because pages doesn't know about `.livello2` yet – it has not been loaded yet. so, either put JS right before closing `</body>` or wrap you javascript code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function () {
        function locationPathname(){
        …
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Added another answer that explains the problem.